# App that moves circle button to random location if user clicks near circle

Tags: java, android, geometry, click

I currently have an Android application that moves a drawn circle to a random location on the screen if I click somewhere on the screen that **isn't** the circle itself.

---

My question is, how could I implement it so that this logic only gets executed when the click happens *relatively* close to the circle? How close isn't strictly defined but, say, if a circle is on the bottom left side of the screen, a click on the top right of the screen would not trigger the circle to move to a new location. I'm imagining something like a square that's slightly larger than the circle which would serve as the hitbox(but still exclude clicks inside the circle)

I assume the changes would have to happen in the *isInsideCircle* function, but I lack the necessary knowledge to understand which variables I should add/subtract to to restrict the region which triggers the logic.
Here is the code that I have at the moment:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new Circle(this));
    }
    public class Circle extends View {
        private float x = 300;
        private float y = 300;
        private int r = 150;
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private Random random = new Random();

        // draws circle
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
        }

        // constructor
        public Circle(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        // gets random coordinates
        void generateRandom() {

            int w = getWidth() - r - 50;
            int h = getHeight()- r - 50;

            int border = r + 50;

            this.x = border + random.nextInt(w-border);
            this.y = border + random.nextInt(h-border);
        }

        // when screen is tapped, old circle removed, new circle drawn
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (!isInsideCircle(event.getX(), event.getY())) { // only register clicks outside of circle
                generateRandom();
                invalidate();
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }


        boolean isInsideCircle(float xPoint, float yPoint) {
            float dx = (x - xPoint);
            float dxPow = (float) Math.pow(dx, 2);
            float dy = (y - yPoint);
            float dyPow = (float) Math.pow(dy, 2);
            float radPow = (float) Math.pow(r, 2);
            return ((dxPow + dyPow) <= radPow));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple parts to this question, that I want to ensure are quite clear before walking through it.

1. We wish to modify the hit area to be a square, rather than a circle
2. We want to invert our logic so instead of reacting when **outside** of the hit area we want to react when it's **inside** our hit area.

I'm actually going to start with the second point first, then move on to the first point.

###### Testing for inside, rather than outside

This one's rather straightforward as you're already testing if a click is **inside** the circle, at least that would be the assumption by the `Circle` class' `isInsideCircle` method. It just so happens that it's fairly safe to assume that if you're **not (!)** inside the circle then you're outside of it. Modifying `if (!isInsideCircle(...))` to `if(isInsideCircle(...))` (remove the not [!]) operator) should help us in that regard, no? Well that was rather painless, hopefully testing to be within a square is as easy!

###### Testing for a square, rather than a circle

... will not be as easy as checking if we're inside, rather than outside, a hit area.
I mean it does require an entire shift in the logic that `isInsideCircle` performs. Also, I'm not sure it's a good idea to change the body of `isInsideCircle` to test if it's inside a **square**. That might be a little confusing, no?

So, it's probably a better idea to make a new method to test if a given (x, y)  coordinate are within a square. Perhaps `isInsideSquare`? Wait a second! A `Square` is most certainly not a `Circle` so, what information do we need to represent a `Square`? Well now we need a way to represent a `Square` AND a way to tell if a coordinate is **within** a square. A square is a special rectangle where you really only need a special coordinate position (a vertex or the exact center) and a side length to compare coordinates against it. We just so happen to have a coordinate position we can use as the center so, I guess we'll need a side length of the hitbox. Lets add a new field to our circle class to represent the hitbox side length. The following line will default it to 50 pixels more than the circle's diameter.

```java
    private int hitboxLength = (2 * r) + 50;
```

Now we have a coordinate point, which, a little unfortunately, is in the **middle** of our square and it's side length. So, how do we determine if a point is within our square hitbox? Well it's nice to know a rectangle can also be described as it's 4 vertices. For a square with side length 2 centered at (0, 0) you would have vertices at (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1), and (-1, 1). In order find out if (x, y) is within our rectangle we just have to not it's within those 4 coordinates. With an X ranging from 1 to -1 and it's Y ranging from 1 to -1 as well. Meaning if x is between -1 and 1 `-1 <= x <= 1` and y is between -1 and 1 `-1 <= y <= 1`.

```java
    boolean isInsideSquare(float xPoint, float yPoint) {
        // The center of a square is HALF it's length from any vertex.
        // Always try to use equivalent number types when comparing
        float halfHitboxLength = this.hitboxLength / 2.0F;
        float xUpperBound = this.x + halfHitboxLength;
        float xLowerBound = this.x - halfHitboxLength;
        // smallest expected X <= xPoint <= largest expected X
        boolean xInSquare = xLowerBound <= xPoint && xPoint <= xUpperBound;

        float yUpperBound = this.y + halfHitboxLength;
        float yLowerBound = this.y - halfHitboxLength;
        boolean yInSquare = yLowerBound <= yPoint && yPoint <= yUpperBound;

        return xInSquare && yInSquare;
    }
```

Now this isn't the most efficient way to handle do this, no doubt, but it *should* provide us the logic of being within our given square.

Now we just have to use `isInsideSquare` rather than `isInsideCircle` within the `onTouchEvent` method.

```java
    // This "if"
    if (!isInsideCircle(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
    // Would become
    if (!isInsideSquare(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
```

However, I can't help but think that representing a Circle with a square feels a little weird. At least, given how different of shapes they are. That's not to mention the question of if `isInsideSquare` even belongs inside a `Circle` class! How would wanting to represent our circle's hit area with another, slightly larger, circle look?

###### Testing for a slightly larger circle

We already have the logic for checking if an (x, y) coordinate pair is inside our current circle. I mean there IS a method called `isInsideCircle`.

```java
        boolean isInsideCircle(float xPoint, float yPoint) {
            float dx = (x - xPoint);
            float dxPow = (float) Math.pow(dx, 2);
            float dy = (y - yPoint);
            float dyPow = (float) Math.pow(dy, 2);
            float radPow = (float) Math.pow(r, 2);
            return ((dxPow + dyPow) <= radPow));
        }
```

Personally, my attention is immediately drawn to a couple places

1. The return `return ((dxPow + dyPow) <= radPow));` which utilizes a few variables, and
2. The variable with no relation to user input `float radPow = (float) Math.pow(r, 2);`

The return, because that's how we determine if the given (`xPoint`, `yPoint`) pair are within our circle instance, but, more importantly, the `radPow` variable, as it appears to be referencing, what I can only assume is, the circle's radius, and to test against a larger circle all we really need to do is adjust the radius of it!

```java
    int userWithinPixels = 50;
    float radPow = (float) Math.pow(r + userWithinPixels, 2);
```

Well that was rather painless!

Again worth pointing out that calling `isInsideCircle` on a `Circle` object might be expected to test if it's inside the the represented circle and not a slightly larger circle, but that's still personal preference and you should do what makes sense for the programmers of the project.

---

##### Using square

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new Circle(this));
    }
    public class Circle extends View {
        private float x = 300;
        private float y = 300;
        private int r = 150;
        // Add hitbox side length
        private int hitboxLength = (2 * r) + 50;
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private Random random = new Random();

        // draws circle
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
        }

        // constructor
        public Circle(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        // gets random coordinates
        void generateRandom() {

            int w = getWidth() - r - 50;
            int h = getHeight()- r - 50;

            int border = r + 50;

            this.x = border + random.nextInt(w-border);
            this.y = border + random.nextInt(h-border);
        }

        // when screen is tapped, old circle removed, new circle drawn
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (isInsideSquare(event.getX(), event.getY())) { // only register clicks outside of circle
                generateRandom();
                invalidate();
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        boolean isInsideSquare(float xPoint, float yPoint) {
            // The center of a square is HALF it's length from any vertex.
            // Always try to use the same number types when comparing/computing
            float halfHitboxLength = this.hitboxLength / 2.0F;
            float xUpperBound = this.x + halfHitboxLength;
            float xLowerBound = this.x - halfHitboxLength;
            // smallest expected X <= xPoint <= largest expected X
            boolean xInSquare = xLowerBound <= xPoint && xPoint <= xUpperBound;

            float yUpperBound = this.y + halfHitboxLength;
            float yLowerBound = this.y - halfHitboxLength;
            boolean yInSquare = yLowerBound <= yPoint && yPoint <= yUpperBound;

            return xInSquare && yInSquare;
        }


        boolean isInsideCircle(float xPoint, float yPoint) {
            float dx = (x - xPoint);
            float dxPow = (float) Math.pow(dx, 2);
            float dy = (y - yPoint);
            float dyPow = (float) Math.pow(dy, 2);
            float radPow = (float) Math.pow(r, 2);
            return ((dxPow + dyPow) <= radPow));
        }
    }
}
```

##### Using larger circle

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new Circle(this));
    }
    public class Circle extends View {
        private float x = 300;
        private float y = 300;
        private int r = 150;
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private Random random = new Random();

        // draws circle
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
        }

        // constructor
        public Circle(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        // gets random coordinates
        void generateRandom() {

            int w = getWidth() - r - 50;
            int h = getHeight()- r - 50;

            int border = r + 50;

            this.x = border + random.nextInt(w-border);
            this.y = border + random.nextInt(h-border);
        }

        // when screen is tapped, old circle removed, new circle drawn
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (isInsideCircle(event.getX(), event.getY())) { // only register clicks outside of circle
                generateRandom();
                invalidate();
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }


        boolean isInsideCircle(float xPoint, float yPoint) {
            float dx = (x - xPoint);
            float dxPow = (float) Math.pow(dx, 2);
            float dy = (y - yPoint);
            float dyPow = (float) Math.pow(dy, 2);
            // maximum amount of pixels user can click off the circle and trigger event
            float userWithinPixels = 25;
            float radPow = (float) Math.pow(r + userWithinPixels, 2);
            return ((dxPow + dyPow) <= radPow));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, thank you very much for your in-depth response and not just providing the solution but also describing the thought process!
Secondly, it works! I just had to adjust the code a bit to satisfy the criteria of it ignoring the clicks inside the circle, but that was accomplished easily by adding  
 `!isInsideCircle(event.getX(), event.getY())` to the if statement inside the `onTouchEvent` function. Once again, thanks!